# Selectize Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I have a selectize dropdown

```
<selectize config="mySelectizeConfig" options="getAvailableObjects(id)""></selectize>
```

On my controller when I return an array works fine

```
$scope.getAvailableObjects=function(id) {
    return $scope.available_objects[id] 
}
```

But when I am trying to filter the array

```
$scope.getAvailableObjects=function(id) {
   var result = [];
   result = $scope.available_objects[id].filter(function(object) {
     return object.is_active;
  });

   return result; 
}
```

Gives me an 'Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached'
How can I troubleshoot that ?

I am getting the same error when I am trying to filter the array on the view.

```
options="available_objects[id] | filter: {'is_active':true}"
```

Comment: what does `$scope.available_objects` look like? is it nested array? do you want to return another array after  you filter it?

Comment: Why don't you just filter the array once and then bind it to `options`instead of bind `options` to a function?

Comment: It's a nested array yes, because I use this array in another place too.

Comment: Avoid `getAvailableObjects` being called all the time. Calculate once (or when something changes again), and put the array into the scope. Access it this way and your error will be gone.

Comment: I am getting the same error when I am trying to filter the array on the view, 
options="available_objects[id] | filter: {'is_active':true}"
gives me the same error.

Comment: are you using angular-selectize? it has a watcher - `$watchCollection` on options used for arrays, not functions. Can you initialise `getAvailableObjects(id)` in the controller and pass the variable into options instead?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey can you explain a bit more, yes I use angular-selectize.

Comment: @Petran well just some variable in the controller `$scope.obj = getAvailableObjects(10)` with `options="obj"`. Of course you can dynamically change it within a function or simply have an array instead: `options="objects[id]"` (which was populated in a for loop like the previous example with a variable)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I am getting the same error when I use an array instead. options="available_objects[id] | filter: {'is_active':true}"

Answer (score 0):

It is because, `Array.prototype.filter` method as well as  `| filter : {'is_active':true}` will always return **new** array, so *$digest() iterations reached*, even though returning arrays look equally. You can fix it by *caching* them:

```
var cache = {};
$scope.getAvailableObjects = function(id) {
   return cache[id] = cache[id] || $scope.available_objects[id].filter(function(object) {
       return object.is_active;
   });
}
```

If `$scope.available_objects` will be changed, you can reset `cache = {}`;